# I keep getting the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a digital humanities project. I inputed

```
filenames = ecco_metadata_w_counts.loc[(ecco_metadata_w_counts["occupation"].str.contains("novelist", na=False)) & (ecco_metadata_w_counts["total_words"] >= 30000)]["DocName"].tolist()
```

I keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-f86a72bd8fb4> in <module>
----> 1 filenames = ecco_metadata_w_counts.loc[(ecco_metadata_w_counts["occupation"].str.contains("novelist", na=False)) & (ecco_metadata_w_counts["total_words"] >= 30000)]["DocName"].tolist()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5463             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5464                 return self[name]
-> 5465             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5466 
   5467     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

The line you wrote as it is doesn't have any issue. I can run it with some test data like:

```py
import pandas as pd

ecco_metadata_w_counts = pd.DataFrame({
     "total_words":[500, 50000], 
     "occupation": ["novelist", "novelist"], 
     "DocName": ["test", "test1" ]
})
ecco_metadata_w_counts.loc[(ecco_metadata_w_counts["occupation"].str.contains("novelist", na=False)) & (ecco_metadata_w_counts["total_words"] >= 30000)]["DocName"].tolist()
```

and get as result:

```
['test1']
```

which matches the condition for the test data I used. Try review your code again.